# Handling a user who keeps removing relevant tags

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

I don't want to call attention to a particular user publicly, but as I was going through the Suggested Edit queue today I came across a user 4 times in a row who is removing relevant tags from questions marking the edit as "removed irrelevant tags".  I keep rejecting these using the "Causes Harm" and "No Improvement Whatsoever" options, but what is the right course of action?  Should a moderator be alerted in this situations?

If it was a one time thing, I'd understand...mistakes & misunderstandings happen.  However, 4 times in a row in the review queue makes me feel like this user does not know what they are doing.

**EDIT**

To answer @Servy's question:

It depends. They were definitely relevant tags. Here are two examples: Question was about multithreading issues experienced in Android and they removed the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) & [multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading) tags. I would say those would be necessary. A second one was questionable though: It was about an issue they experienced trying to do something in particular with a ListView control in Android, and they removed the [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview) tag, which isn't android specific

Comment: Are you sure the tag was actually necessary?

Comment: @Servy Added examples to question.

Comment: Keep in mind what tags are there for.  They're there primarily so that people following those tags can find questions that interest them.  Even if a question involves some topic in some way, it would need to be a question that people following that tag would want to see for that tag to belong there.  For example, an android question may tangentially involve some amount of Java code, but if the real problem is separate from the actual Java code and more about the environment you wouldn't want to be driving java experts to the question, you'd want to be driving android experts to the question.

Comment: @Servy That makes sense.  However, when there is overlap in the constructs being used or the standard Java library is being used wouldn't we want to drive more attention to the question by including both Java & Android folks?

Comment: The fundamental question is would you want someone who know a lot about Java and knew nothing about android to see the question?  Would such a person likely be helpful?  If not, the tag probably doesn't belong.  If yes, then it would.  The answer to that question will of course be very dependent on the specifics of the question being asked.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the input.  I'll keep that in mind.  As someone who is proficient in both Java on it's own and Android dev I'll need to make sure I'm being objective when making this call making sure to differentiate between the two.

Comment: @JNYRanger also make sure that the edit is also complete (and that there aren't other problems with the post that still need to be handled).

Comment: @ryanyuyu These were tag only edits

Comment: @JNYRanger then your review actions sound fine.  As for mod attention, I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

If it looks like the user is acting in good faith, and really believes that the tag shouldn't be on the question (but you disagree with them), simply post a comment to the user and explain why you think the tag belongs on the question, and let them explain why they think it doesn't.  If you end up starting a lengthy discussion, consider moving the discussion to chat or meta.

If you feel the user is acting maliciously, and removing tags knowing full well that they belong on the question in an attempt to abuse the question, just flag for moderator attention, decline any suggested edits you see, and let the mod take care of the rest; don't engage with the user as there isn't anything productive you can do.

Comment: I don't particularly believe that they were acting maliciously in this case.